# Removing White Space Between Images in SIGIL

Tags: html, css, epub

I'm new to working with HTML and I've been trying to format a linked Table of Contents of images in SIGIL, an ePub editor. I've linked all of my images successfully (yay!) to their appropriate chapter headings in the book, but all the images on the chapter list of the TOC come out with white spaces between them. I can't seem to get rid of the white spaces... at all. I even set the font-size to 0 and it does nothing.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="../Text/Prologue.htm#Anchor-for-prologue"
style="font-size: 1.125em; line-height: 1.2;"><img alt="Prologue"
src="../Images/prologueTOC.jpg" /></a><a href="../Text/Prologue.htm#
Anchor-for-prologue"><br /></a>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well this code above doesn't give us enough information to really help with your problem. So you're setting `font-size` to `0` and the problem persists. How about `height` of the img or setting `display` property of the image to `block` or using the image as `background-image` of the anchor? And leave out the double anchor, what's that for? What spaces do you mean exactly? Horizontal space between the image and what? In your code is just one image referenced.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding!

I'm sorry I didn't provide enough information. It wasn't intentional, I assure you.

The images are vertical, so the space is coming in between the images. Here's a link to a screenshot on imgur: http://i.imgur.com/y4Yd4qH.jpg

The code I posted is all the same, stacked on top of one another.

Comment: I see images aside, but 'Chapter 19' & 'Chapter 20' as text in the middle, where is that reflected in your code above? Please update your post and put in all the code encapsulating the lines Chapter 19, Chapter 20 and Epilogue. Or are the words part of the images?

Comment: The words are part of the images. It was a larger image that I sliced horizontally to allow SIGIL to link the different parts. There's no actual text there - each one is an image.

Comment: Could you come up with a *jsfiddle* putting in your code and replacing the local image paths with paths to the images on a webserver? Two or three rows are optimal.